# Jitpack not working

Tags: maven, github, jitpack

I'm trying to compile my Github repository using Jitpack.
I've used:

```
<repository>
  <id>jitpack.io</id>
  <url>https://jitpack.io/
</repository>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bys1</groupId>
  <artifactId>importer</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-Beta</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm now getting a ClassNotFoundException. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml is totally malformed. Change it to this.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.bys1</groupId>
        <artifactId>importer</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-Beta</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I was able to load your classes (ImporterPlugin, etc.) with that.

Comment: I have used that but it did not work. I got the classes but it didn't compile it.